# Highcharts trigger background click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts to trigger an event when the background is clicked:

```
$("#my-chart").highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: "pie",
        events: {
            click: function() {
                console.log("I'm working!"); // This is the event I want to trigger
            };
        }
    }
 });
 var myChart = $("#my-chart").highcharts();
```

I would like to trigger this event when clicking on something outside of the chart. For example:

```
<button>Trigger the Highcharts Event!</button>
<script>
    $("button").on('click', function() {
        // I'd like to trigger the event here
        // $('#my-chart').click(); does nothing
        // myChart.chart.events.click(); does nothing
        // myChart.events.click(); does nothing
        // $('#my-chart').find('rect.highcharts-background').click() does nothing
    });
</script>
```

How can I trigger the event programmatically?

---

I've tried several things to get more information. Looking at `arguments.callee.caller.name`, the value is `""` (empty string).
`arguments.callee.caller` gives me the following:

```
function (a){a=m.event.fix(a);var b,c,e,f,g,h=[],i=d.call(arguments),j=(m._data(this,"events")||{})[a.type]||[],k=m.event.special[a.type]||{};if(i[0]=a,a.delegateTarget=this,!k.preDispatch||k.preDispatch.call(this,a)!==!1){h=m.event.handlers.call(this,a,j),b=0;while((f=h[b++])&&!a.isPropagationStopped()){a.currentTarget=f.elem,g=0;while((e=f.handlers[g++])&&!a.isImmediatePropagationStopped())(!a.namespace_re||a.namespace_re.test(e.namespace))&&(a.handleObj=e,a.data=e.data,c=((m.event.special[e.origType]||{}).handle||e.handler).apply(f.elem,i),void 0!==c&&(a.result=c)===!1&&(a.preventDefault(),a.stopPropagation()))}return k.postDispatch&&k.postDispatch.call(this,a),a.result}}
```

Ain't nobody got time to decipher that!

A bit more useful information is the `event.target`, which is `rect.highcharts-background`. Triggering a click on that does nothing. Absolutely nothing. I've made a few other attempts, all within the comments in the `$('button').click()` function above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `fireEvent` function and then `trigger` this from the outside.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/er90yeem/1/

Comment: This is fantastic! Thank you so much! Your comments regarding the errors helped out so much!

Comment: @sebastian The jsfiddle is not working . Nothing is being logged to the console.